# JavaScript algorithm question: trying to implement a JSON parsing function to output a string in a prettier format

Tags: javascript, json

I am well aware of the existence of `JSON.parse` and `JSON.stringify` and `prettier` the npm package. But for some reason I still have to do this by hand. Think of it as a coding interview question and please do not close this question simply because I could have used `JSON.parse` and `JSON.stringify`, as I said there is this constraint. And this question is NOT a duplicate of this [pretty-print JSON using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4810841/pretty-print-json-using-javascript)

Here is a string `"['foo', {bar:['baz',null,1.0,2]}]"`

I wanted to implement a function to return a string denoting a json object with proper indentaion.

i.e. the output **string** should be

```
   [
        "foo", 
        {
            "bar":
            [
                "baz", 
                null, 
                1.0, 
                2
            ]
        }
    ]
```

Here is my attempt

```js
function printJSON(str) {
    let spaces = [];
    let output = '';

    str.split('').forEach(char => {
        switch(char) {
            case '{':
            case '[':
                spaces.push('    ');
                output += char + '\n' + spaces.join('');
                break;
            case '}':
            case ']':
                spaces.pop();
                output += '\n' + spaces.join('') + char;
                break;
            case ',':
                output += char + '\n' + spaces.join('');
                break;
            default:
                output += char;
                break;
        }
    });

    console.log(output);
    return output
}
```

However the output format is slightly off as in

```
[ 
    "foo", 
     { 
        bar:[ // 
            "baz", 
            null, 
            1.0, 
            2 
        ] 
    } 
]
```

How can I fix this format issue? also is there a more elegant way or alternative way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this, since you also need to add a carriage return after the colon:

```
function printJSON(str) {
    let spaces = [];
    let output = '';

    str.split('').forEach(char => {
        switch (char) {
            case '{':
            case '[':
                spaces.push('    ');
                output += char + '\n' + spaces.join('');
                break;
            case ':':
                output += char + '\n' + spaces.join('');
                break;
            case '}':
            case ']':
                spaces.pop();
                output += '\n' + spaces.join('') + char;
                break;
            case ',':
                output += char + '\n' + spaces.join('');
                break;
            default:
                output += char;
                break;
        }
    });

    console.log(output);
    return output
}

let string = "['foo', {bar:['baz',null,1.0,2]}]";
printJSON(string);
```