# How to append newlines to json?

Tags: javascript, json

I am working on a Discord bot and want to save currency values in a json file. It's working just fine so far, but it's appending them to the json file in one single line and although it is entirely functional, I would like to be able to read it.

This is the code

```
                let json = jsonfile.readFileSync(balance, { throws: false })

            let newBalance = {}

            for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                let val = embedJSON.fields[i].value
                val = val.replace(",", "")
                let valSplit = val.split(" ")[1]

                newBalance[`${embedJSON.fields[i].name}`] = valSplit

            }
            json[`${user}`] = newBalance
            jsonfile.writeFileSync(balance, json)
```

And this is what the json looks like

```
{"Anth'auwe#0169":{"Cash:":"200","Bank:":"399800","Net Worth:":"400000"},"Layers#0169":{"Cash:":"0","Bank:":"199838","Net Worth:":"199838"}}
```

If possible, I would like for it to look like this

```
    {
    "Layers#0169": {
        "Cash": 0,
        "Bank": 0,
        "Net Worth": 0
    },
    "Anth'auwe#0169": {
        "cash": 0,
        "bank": 0,
        "Net Worth": 0
    }
    }
```

Comment: Try adding `\n` or `\r`

Comment: @Ivar Yes and no. I would prefer for it to just be pretty by default, without having to print it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you tried to read the doc of jsonfile package ?

`jsonfile.writeFileSync(balance, json, { spaces: 2 })`

Answer (score 2):

I think that you're looking how to pretty save your JSON.

As explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7220510/7491884) you can do it the same way the [`JSON.stringify()` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) does using the `spaces` option.

Try changing this line:

```
jsonfile.writeFileSync(balance, json)
```

For this one:

```
jsonfile.writeFileSync(balance, json, {spaces: 2})
```

```js
const myJSON = {"Anth'auwe#0169":{"Cash:":"200","Bank:":"399800","Net Worth:":"400000"},"Layers#0169":{"Cash:":"0","Bank:":"199838","Net Worth:":"199838"}};

console.log(JSON.stringify(myJSON, null, 2));
```