# How to prettyfy json with \n?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

Is there a way to turn `{"query":{"match_all" : {} }}` into `{\n  "query":{\n    "match_all" : {}\n  }\n}`?

I have tried with

```
const stringify = require("json-stringify-pretty-compact");

const a = '{\n  "query":{\n    "match_all" : {}\n  }\n}';
const b = '{"query":{"match_all" : {} }}';
console.log(a);
console.log(b);
const c = stringify(b);
console.log(c);
```

where I get

```
{
  "query":{
    "match_all" : {}
  }
}


{"query":{"match_all" : {} }}
"{\"query\":{\"match_all\" : {} }}"
```

For some reason the `\n`'s are missing.

Comment: `stringify`!=`prettify`. You should pass an object to it, not a JSON text.

Comment: This is a little unclear. Do you want the output to contain the literal characters `\n`?

Comment: Do you want to pretty existing JSON data (i.e. text) or a JavaScript value? If the latter then it's a duplicate of [pretty-print JSON using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4810841/218196)

Comment: @SimonBrahan Yes, I would like to have the `\n`'s and white spaces inserted, so the variable becomes `{\n  "query":{\n    "match_all" : {}\n  }\n}`

Comment: @Bergi The reason I gave https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-stringify-pretty-compact a try was because it looked like the purpose of the package were to prettify the string.

Comment: @FelixKling Yes, but the outout should have `\n` and white spaces inserted, so it becomes `{\n  "query":{\n    "match_all" : {}\n  }\n}`.

Comment: @SandraSchlichting No. The docs state "*it’s like `JSON.stringify`*". With prettier output than the native method, yes, but still the same interface - you need to pass data not JSON strings.

Comment: It's still not quite clear to me what your actual input is. If it is JSON (i.e. text) you should be able to use https://prettier.io/ to prettify it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whoops, it looks like you need to parse that JSON first.

Try this:

```js
const stringify = require("json-stringify-pretty-compact");

const a = '{\n  "query":{\n    "match_all" : {}\n  }\n}';
const b = '{"query":{"match_all" : {} }}';
console.log(a);
console.log(b);
const c = stringify(JSON.parse(b));
console.log(c);
```

---

You can use `JSON.stringify` instead – Just set the third argument to a `number` (to indent by that many spaces) or a `string` (to indent by that string).

Just set the second argument to null for now

Example:

```js
const a = '{\n  "query":{\n    "match_all" : {}\n  }\n}';
const b = '{"query":{"match_all":{}}}';
console.log(a);
console.log(b);
const c = JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(b), null, 4);
console.log(c);
```

---

Another option, if you are just debugging, would be to use `require('util').inspect(obj)`, which `console.log`s the object. But the advantage of this method is that you can choose between a compact format or the normal format, you can apply syntax highlighting, and you can even choose the depth of the object to be logged. There's more info [here](https://dev.to/siddharthshyniben/the-node-js-util-module-3nbd#:%7E:text=now%2C%20you%20may%20think%20it%20is%20just%20an%20equivalent%20of%20console.log(json.stringify(obj))%2C%20but%20there%20is%20a%20lot%20more%20functionality%20available%20using%20the%20options%20object.%20some%20of%20the%20more%20useful%20options%20are%3A) and [here](https://nodejs.org/en/knowledge/getting-started/how-to-use-util-inspect/),
but I think you could use `require('util').inspect(obj, { depth: Infinity, colors: true, compact: false })`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this ?

`JSON.stringify(b, null, 2) // 2 for 2 whitespace indent`
`.replace(/\n/g, '\\n') // To display \n rather than an actual line return`

```js
const obj = {"query":{"match_all" : {} }}

console.log(JSON.stringify(obj, null,2).replace(/\n/g, '\\n'))
```

Comment: I think `\n`s in OP's example meant to be *real* linefeeds, otherwise you're right