# Formatting JSON string in a readable way

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, human-readable

I have a json file created in javascript that includes a script as in the following simplified example:

*script1.json*

```
{ 
   "name": "script1",
   ... <many other properties> 
   "script": "date as timestamp,\n\t\tid as integer,\n\t\tfirst_name as string,\n\t\tlast_name as string"
}
```

The script can get very long, and sometimes I have to look at these files and it is unreadble. As such I'm considering storing the script as an array as follows, simply treating `\n` as new array item and `\t` as some number of spaces

*script1-new.json*

```
{ 
   "name": "script1",
   ... <many other properties> 
   "script": ["date as timestamp,",
              "        id as integer,",
              "        first_name as string,",
              "        last_name as string"]
}
```

Is there any better way to display this sort of string in a readable format in json? Is there any best practice for doing this sort of conversion from `string -> array` and vice versa in javascript?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4810841/pretty-print-json-using-javascript

Comment: Does this answer your question? [pretty-print JSON using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4810841/pretty-print-json-using-javascript)

Comment: Use `data.script.split("\n")` to split the script string into multiple lines.

Comment: @JakobLovern That won't show how to split the script into multiple strings.