# Display pretty print of JSON in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I wonder how do people display pretty print of JSON in Vue.js

[image]

```
<v-expansion-panels>
  <v-expansion-panel v-for="(entrie, i) in objects.log.entries" :key="i">
    <v-expansion-panel-header class="text-left">

      {{ entrie.request.postData.text }}
    </v-expansion-panel-header>
    <v-expansion-panel-content class="green--text">

      {{ entrie.response.content.text }}

    </v-expansion-panel-content>
  </v-expansion-panel>
</v-expansion-panels>
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bheng/pkc28b64/)

Just to make my point clear, I'm hoping to see something like this :

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7220510

Answer (score 6):

You can add a [filter](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/filters.html) to *stringify* the data in a nicer format.

```js
filters: {
  pretty: (val, indent = 2) => {
    if (typeof val !== "object") {
      try {
        val = JSON.parse(val)
      } catch (err) {
        console.warn("value is not JSON")
        return val
      }
     
      return JSON.stringify(val, null, indent)
    }
  }
}
```

Use CSS `white-space` or simply use a `<pre>` tag to keep formatting in your template

```html
<pre>{{ entrie.response.content.text | pretty(4) }}</pre>
```

Demo ~ https://jsfiddle.net/ktz49q1h/

---

Note that filters are not supported in Vue3. See the [migration strategy](https://v3-migration.vuejs.org/breaking-changes/filters.html#filters) for solutions.