# Remove a string using Ternary operation in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json, object, conditional-operator

I have something like this in my console: How can I take out the [object Object] from my output?

I want the output printed without the [Object Object]. Probably using a ternary operation?

```
data:[object Object]
  text:Data is supplied by Government
  link:https://en.wikipedia.org/
```

This is my code:

```js
const GetData = (obj, step) => {

    let padSpace = ""

    for (let j=0; j < step; j++) {
      padSpace += ''
    }

    for (let k in obj) {
      console.log(padSpace + k + ':' + obj[k])
      if (typeof(obj[k]) === "object") {
        if (Array.isArray(obj[k])) {
          obj[k].forEach(element => {
              if (typeof(element === "object")) {
                GetData(element, step + 1);
              } else {
                console.log(padSpace + element)
              }
            }
          );
        } else {
          GetData(obj[k], step + 1);
        }
      } else {}
    }
```

I want something like:

Comment: Seems like you don't want to console.log the element if the element is an object.  You already have an if that checks, you could put the initial console.log inside the (currently empty) else, below.

Comment: Sure you could console.log padString and prop, but not entity[prop], when the item is an object (inside the if that checks).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following test will always pass because `typeof true` and `typeof false` are both `"boolean"` which is truthy.

```js
if (typeof(element === "object")) {
```

Try

```js
if (typeof element === "object") {
```

I have no idea why you are talking about a ternary operation.

---

To avoid the `[object Object]`  you can move the existing `console.log` and add another one as shown:

```js
for (let prop in entity) {  
  if (typeof entity[prop] === "object") {
    console.log(padString + prop + ':');
    if (Array.isArray(entity[prop])) {
      entity[prop].forEach(element => {
        if (typeof element === "object") {
          formatData(element, level + 1);
        } else {
          console.log(padString + element)
        }
      });
    } else {
      formatData(entity[prop], level + 1);
    }
  } else {
    console.log(padString + prop + ':' + entity[prop])
  }
}
```

Comment: that doesn't work

Comment: @Tini Updated with example of how to get rid of the unwanted string.

Answer (score 1):

I am not an expert but I'll try to help here.

This data is coming from an external API, I suppose. Right?
It seems to me that is just a matter of how the data is being sent back from the server. Maybe you just need to use JSON.stringfy to convert the object to string.

It would be nice to have access to the kind of data being sent from the server to manipulate it.

Hope it starts to help you in a way...

Cheers

Comment: This might be the simplest way.  Check https://stackoverflow.com/a/7220510/535480 to implement the equivalent of padString.