# How to display dynamic string JSON into Div or Textarea in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, json

I am calling an API it is returning the dynamic JSON, I want to just display this into the DIV or TEXTAREA.

JSON Can be :
{"id":255,"Val2":"\n  {"Id": 28, "deta": "\n  {\n   \"strategy1\":{\"$type\":\"Text1, text2\"}}"}"}

or

{"id":251,"name":"text", enable:true}

**Expected result:**

```
    {
      "id":255,
      "Val1":
       {
          Id: 28, 
          "deta": 
          {
            "strategy1":
            {
              "$type":"text1, text2"
            }
          }
       }
    }
```

Comment: Please fix the [format](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) and show us what you've tried so far to solve this on your own.

Comment: _"JSON Can be ... or ..."_ - Both of the examples are _not_ [JSON](https://www.json.org/json-en.html)

Answer (score 0):

( yoinked from the following answer already )

https://stackoverflow.com/a/7220510/20053031

```js
const obj = resultOfYourRequest;
const prettyString = JSON.stringify(obj, null, 2);

document.getElementById('your-element-id').innerHtml = prettyString;
```

Comment: I already used the above method like:`function output(inp) {
    document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('pre')).innerHTML = inp;
}

var obj =  {
  "id": 255,
  "Val2": "\n {\"name\":\"test\"}"
};;
const prettyString = JSON.stringify(obj, null, 2);

output(prettyString);`  Result: `{
    "id": 255,
    "Val2": "\n {\"name\":\"test\"}"
}` but it does not format what I expected Result:`{
  "id": 255,
  "Val2": {
    "name": "test"
  }
}`

Comment: The formatting of your comment does not give a clear picture of what went wrong here, what are you expecting? More indentation?